# How to retrieve data with composite primary key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working with four tables in Laravel and trying to display data to a view.  I believe I am stuck because one of the tables has a composite primary key.

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    //Get application for drug
    $application = PharmaApplication::where('ApplNo', $id)->first();

    //Return all products for application
    $drugs = $application->products;

    return view('profiles.drug', compact('drugs'));
}
```

I have the following in my PharmaApplication model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PharmaProduct', 'ApplNo', 'ApplNo');
}
```

I have the following in my view (which I cannot complete)

```
@foreach ($drugs as $drug) 
  <li>{{$drug->Strength}}</li>
  <li>{{$drug->Form}}</li>
  <li>{{$drug->Form}}</li>
@endforeach
```

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Get the application for a drug - this part of my code works
2. Return an array of objects for the products (i.e. 7 products that belong to one application). I can do this but get stuck going to the next part.
3. Next, I have to use the array of objects and search a table with the following columns: MarketingStatusID, ApplNo, ProductNo. I know how to query this table and get one row using DB Query, but then how do I get the proper result to that query within the for loop in my view?
4. Finally, I use the MarketingStatusID to retrieve the MarketingStatusDescription which I will know how to do.

Comment: What model are these values in: MarketingStatusID, ApplNo, ProductNo. Also what exactly do you mean by "search a table with the following columns"?

Comment: those values are in the PharmaMarketingStatus model.  I usually do a model relationship but the table associated with that model has a composite primary key.  By 'search a table with the following columns', I meant I was going to use DB Query and use where clauses

Comment: As you mention, your composite key is complicating simple things, you can change that or use queries with where or find using the keys from other tables where you cannot use a relationship